# UITableViewCell label is not updating

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have seen many posts on here but nothing seems to be working. I am trying to update a custom UITableViewCell label that is setup in storyboard. I am using this code when I receive an update notification during the download:

```
NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:MyObject];
MyListTableViewCell *cell = (MyListTableViewCell *)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:index];
//get the update value then
cell.bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB of %.1f MB", megaBytesDownloaded, totalDownloadEstimate];
```

I can see in logs the values are correct, and my breakpoint on the update line is hit exactly when it should be, but the label only updates when I interact with the cell, or for some reason,a few seconds after my download process has completed.

I am using AFNetworking and all of my IBOutlets have been checked again and again.

How can I update the cell in real time?

Comment: this sounds like the kind of behavior you'd see if your code is not running on the main/UI thread

Comment: Sounds like you're not reloading the tableview.

Comment: (And you should never update a tableview cell directly.  Always update the dataSource and then reload the cell.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling cellForRowAtIndexPath outside of a tableView reload. This will either give you a reused cell or a brand new instance but not the cell shown on the screen at the time.

What you should do is call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation.`

Your code should have a dataSource that you update where you are currently trying to update the cell's bottomLabel.

Then your code should look something like this:

```
self.dataSource.megaBytesDownloaded = megaBytesDownloaded;
self.dataSource.totalDownloadEstimate = totalDownloadEstimate;

NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:MyObject];
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

And then in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can update your cell's bottomLabel at that point.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //Your normal setup code here
    cell.bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB of %.1f MB", self.dataSource.megaBytesDownloaded, self.dataSource.totalDownloadEstimate];
}
```

Since it looks like you are also using AFNetworking to observe the download progress, you should also look into throwing your view update code on the main thread. AFNetworking uses multithreading in this case to prevent any jumps or lags in your UI. I would suggest using GCD to allow the main thread to handle updating your UI code.

It should look something like this:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //view update code here.
});
```

Comment: You had it in your first answer. Even using reloadRows, I had to dispatch it to the main thread. Label updated right away. I don't understand, is that AFNetworking? How can it keep cell updates on the background thread?

Comment: I'll update my answer to have both answers in one. AFNetworking does their download updates on a background thread in order to keep from blocking the view thread (the main thread). By doing this, it allows you to observe the download progress without causing jumps in your UI.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think accessing a cell the way you did is a good idea. I would suggest this

in your - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath   have the following line

```
cell.bottomLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f MB of %.1f MB", megaBytesDownloaded, totalDownloadEstimate];
```

and after NSIndexPath *index = [self.fetchedResultsController indexPathForObject:MyObject]; add this line of code

```
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[index] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone;
```

**Hope This Helps**

Comment: Did not work. Apparently, it was updating on a background tread. As soon as I put my cell.bottomLabel.text = on the main thread, it worked a treat. Even calling reloadRows, I still had to use the main thread in cellForRowAtIndexPath. I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using:

```
  - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
```

Instead directly assigning values to table cell.