# IOS 11 table did select issue

Tags: uitableview, ios11

I am working with table for setting values from the array to a label in a row.
In ios 10 when I select table row it works but in ios 11 when I select a row the cell label value replace with Label text only.
Can any one help.
Here is the code I have done:=

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return arrpickuprequest.count;
}
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
            cell.lblName.text = [[arrpickuprequest objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1]valueForKey:@"Name"];
          cell.btncheck.tag = indexPath.row;

        if([[arrpickuprequestChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
            [cell.btncheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheck"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        else
            [cell.btncheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"check"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [cell.btncheck addTarget:self action:@selector(purchase_click:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        return cell;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        if (indexPath.row==0) {
            if([[arrpickuprequestChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
                                {
                                    for (int i=0; i<[arrpickuprequest count]+1; i++) {
                                        [arrpickuprequestChecked replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"Check"];
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    for (int i=0; i<[arrpickuprequest count]+1; i++) {
                                        [arrpickuprequestChecked replaceObjectAtIndex:i withObject:@"Uncheck"];

                                    }
                                }
        }
        else {
            if([[arrpickuprequestChecked objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] isEqualToString:@"Uncheck"])
                {
                    [arrpickuprequestChecked replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Check"];
                }
                else
                {
                    [arrpickuprequestChecked replaceObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row withObject:@"Uncheck"];
                    [arrpickuprequestChecked replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Uncheck"];
                }
            }
            [tblPickupreuest reloadData];
}
```

Comment: A piece of code in question would be nice.

Comment: @ArpitDongre I have added the code. :)

Comment: Instead of reloading the whole tableView, you can reload few rows only. Try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27322605/5620628). Not fully sure if it will work in your case.